# QBitArray получить значение в QString

Tags: qt

Задаю произвольный массив:

```
QBitArray msg (8);
msg.setBit(7, listBit.at(1).toInt());
msg.setBit(6, listBit.at(2).toInt());
msg.setBit(5, listBit.at(3).toInt());
msg.setBit(4, listBit.at(4).toInt());
msg.setBit(3, listBit.at(5).toInt());
msg.setBit(2, listBit.at(6).toInt());
msg.setBit(1, listBit.at(7).toInt());
msg.setBit(0, listBit.at(8).toInt());
```

при этом массив может быть и на 16 бит, и так далее.

Мне нужно получить из этого значение и вывести его.

В интернете есть функция:

```
QByteArray bitsToBytes(const QBitArray &bits)
{
    QByteArray bytes;
    bytes.resize(bits.size()/8);

    // Convert from QBitArray to QByteArray
    for(int b=0; b<bits.count(); ++b)
        bytes[b/8] = (bytes.at(b/8) | ((bits[b]?1:0)<<(b%8)));
    return bytes;
}
```

Однако результат выдает неправильный.

Подскажите пожалуйста как реализовать?

Answer (score 4):

Похоже, что не делается округление вниз в `bytes.at(b/8)`. Наверное, лучше так:

```
QByteArray bitsToBytes(const QBitArray &bits) {
    QByteArray bytes;
    bytes.resize(bits.size()/8);

    for(int b = 0; b < bits.count(); ++b)
        bytes[b/8] = (bytes.at(std::floor(b/8)) | ((bits[b]?1:0)<<(b%8)));

    return bytes;
}
```

А ещё можно поступить проще, правда, с небольшим оверхедом:

```
QBitArray msg(8);
msg.setBit(7, 1);
msg.setBit(6, 1);
msg.setBit(5, 1);
msg.setBit(4, 1);
msg.setBit(3, 1);
msg.setBit(2, 1);
msg.setBit(1, 1);
msg.setBit(0, 1);

QByteArray data;

QDataStream stream(&data, QIODevice::WriteOnly);
stream << msg;

data.remove(0, sizeof(quint32));

qDebug() << data;
```

Предпоследняя строка удалит размер битового массива, который записывается в поток при сериализации.

Comment: Пишет ошибку 

C:\Qt\Qt5.3.2\Tools\QtCreator\bin\ftdi\main.cpp:31: ошибка: 'floor' is not a member of 'std'
         bytes[b/8] = (bytes.at(std::floor(b/8)) | ((bits[b]?1:0)<<(b%8)));
                                ^

Comment: Подключите заголовочный файл "<cmath>" через `include`.